Wideband Dipole Antenna Ideas
I am home brewing an FM radio and have this so far. It works great for stations within +-5 MHz of my antennas resonance, but I want to hear more stations farther away on the spectrum. For this reason I chose roughly the middle of the FM radio spectrum (95 MHz) but want better reception at the ends.
The L network formed by the 350nH inductor and 680pF capacitor nearest the antenna match my amplifier to ~75 Ohms. My antenna is ~95 MHz resonant due to its leg lengths, and this neighborhood is also where I have the best reception experimentally. For this reason, I believe that the problem lies between the dipole and 75 ohm RG6 transmission line.
I have read about using thicker AWG antenna legs for broader resonance bandwidth ("fat dipoles") but there seems to be limited information on the topic. Similarly, I have heard of multiband dipoles, and the idea of paralleling two more lengths of wire to form a second dipole at another end of the spectrum could work but is spatially inconvenient.
Are there other ways to match an antenna to transmission line across a 20 MHz spectrum?




Log-periodic antennas are wide bandwidth, plus have gain and are directional. Your antenna connection looks like you are using a power supply cable with a coaxial power connector. Using a proper transmission line (coax or twin-lead) may be more helpful than a wide band antenna.

I used Rg6 coax with a snap-on ferrite choke to act as a balun, though I suppose the picture resolution doesn't help convey that. Legs are soldered directly to the f-connector.

Anything that widens the elements will help to increase bandwidth.
Note that you can treat a dipole as a resonant tank coupled to free space and to the receiver.  Both of these are loss elements, which act to de-Q the resonant tank.  If we increase that coupling, the Q can be reduced.  It isn't sufficient to increase feedpoint impedance -- we still need that matched for power transfer, so we must match both feedpoint and resonator impedances, and whatever radiation resistance that picks up in turn.
For the dipole, fatter elements increase coupling to space.  A bowtie is a typical configuration, and can be constructed using the wire you have been using.  Just add more wires of similar length and fan them out.
A fan of wires (joined between each other along the length, or not) is too closely coupled to act as independent elements, so this isn't a multiband strategy.
You could however space elements of nearby length, wired in parallel (with some phasing due to the wiring), in which case you would end up with something resembling a log periodic antenna.  If the ratio between successive elements is large, there might be gaps in the reception band, and you have a multiband antenna.  If the elements are in geometric series, and a particular arrangement, you get a log periodic, which can have very wide bandwidth indeed (>10:1 is available).
In general, the more elements you add, that are some relevant distance apart (λ/4 give or take, etc.), you are having some impact on directionality, and so should place them in relative orientation to suit some goal.
This is very hand-waving of course, and the harsh realities of fields and phasing do matter.  Sticking to solved antenna designs is preferred.

It's also not obvious if you're actually getting the antenna response as designed/intended.  You seem to be using an audio or power cable for the feedline, with at best, a ferrite bead on it?  This does not make an effective balun, and the high impedance of your thin elements will not match well to the line (which itself may be lossy; common PVC insulation is not to be underestimated above even a few MHz).  Use a proper coax cable (polyethylene or etc. dielectric), or twin lead (which will match better to a folded dipole -- which can also be readily made out of the same stuff), and a proper balun design (for a 50Ω input port, a 1:4 impedance balun is easy to make with a couple twisted pairs and a ferrite core).  Without a good balun, you are receiving feedline radiation, as well as any common-mode energy circulating around the receiver and connected equipment.
The input network also seems sub-par: Fair-Rite (the manufacturer of Amidon's FT37-43 and other products) does not provide impedance data for the 5943000201, but a roughly similar suppression bead exists: 
2643375102 EMI Suppression Bead | Fair-Rite 
Having an impedance of 54Ω at 100MHz, largely resistive, won't be doing your input network any favors.  And the 5943000201 is half height, so probably about half the impedance.  I would suggest at least 6 turns to act as an RFC.  Alternately, stick with air-core inductors; the input filter can even be a double-tuned design to spread bandwidth across the full FM BCB.
There are further issues with the amplifiers, but I've already digressed far enough from the given topic that I'll leave this as a hint for further study.

I will try to optimize my setup then. The antenna feedline in the picture is RG6 coax with a snap-on ferrite choke; dipole legs are soldered directly to the F-connector. My intention with the FT37-43 core was to shunt low frequency AM stations to ground so they wouldn't be amplified (which did work). I used ltspice to simulate input impedance of my amplifier and an online L-network calculator to find a highpass configuration that would match 75 ohms to amplifier impedance. I am curious about your views on the amplifiers. LTspice didnt match reality once emitter bypass caps were added.

Ah okay, so that's not so bad. A proper balun will clean that up then. You may find further reading of interest, such as: what differences there are between simulators and real life, transistor models and how they're modeled at all, how to measure a real one yourself, etc. Somewhat alarming is the hFE note on the schematic -- understanding how real devices vary will be useful direction here (we like to avoid this so-called "suicide biasing" arrangement).

Thanks for clarifying. Agreed, the biasing scheme was a compromise. I am excited to dig into those topics and learn more about antennas and configurations too though.
